# "break one's habit of", "break the habit of", "break one's .... habit", are they formal?

Tags: formality

Consider the following sentences:

1. He is trying to **break his habit of** biting his nails.
2. He is trying to **break the habit of** biting his nails.
3. He is trying to **break his** nail-biting **habit.**
4. He is trying to **stop** biting his nails.

In my native language, sentences 1 to 3 sound formal because the word "habit" is used. In casual conversations we would say the last sentence.

Is this the same in English? Do sentences 1 to 3 sound formal?

Comment: There is nothing especially formal about the word 'habit'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 & 2 sound wrong, with to many he/his's flying around. I would also question the use of break in 1-3. Does he want to resume biting his nails at a latter date? Break can be End or Interrupt. Number 4 is fine.

Number 3 I would modify

> He is trying to stop his *nail-biting habit*.

This format is quite acceptable

> From that point on, he apparently developed a *bad drinking habit* and struggled with various health problems.

Arguably this arrangement would sound more formal.

> He has a bad habit of biting his nails, which he is trying to stop.

---